# Контейнер внутри списка PyQt

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, listwidget

Я пытаюсь сделать список фильмов в виде списка на *PyQt*.
Виджет `QListWidget` способен хранить только строки.

Есть ли виджет, который может внутри себя хранить контейнер с виджетами и отображаться в виде списка?

Comment: в чем проблема перевести это все в строку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, все можно реализовать. Как вариант:

> void QListWidget::setItemWidget(QListWidgetItem *item, QWidget *widget)
>
> Устанавливает виджет, который будет отображаться в данном элементе.
>
> Эту функцию следует использовать только для отображения статического содержимого
> вместо элемента виджета списка.
> Если вы хотите отображать настраиваемый динамический контент или реализовать
> настраиваемый виджет редактора, используйте вместо этого QListView
> и подкласс QStyledItemDelegate.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QPushButton,\
    QListWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QListWidget, QApplication, QGridLayout, QLabel


class ItemWidget(QWidget):
    itemDeleted = pyqtSignal(QListWidgetItem)

    def __init__(self, text, item, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ItemWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._item = item                 # Сохраните ссылку на объект элемента списка
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel(f'Hello {text}', self), 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(QLineEdit(text, self),  1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton('x', self, clicked=self.doDeleteItem), 0, 1, 2, 1)        

    def doDeleteItem(self):
        self.itemDeleted.emit(self._item)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        # Список
        self.listWidget = QListWidget(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)

        # Кнопка очистки
        self.clearBtn = QPushButton('Очистить весь список', self, clicked=self.doClearItem)
        layout.addWidget(self.clearBtn)

        # Добавить данные
        self.testData()

    def doDeleteItem(self, item):
        # Получить количество строк, соответствующих item
        row = self.listWidget.indexFromItem(item).row()
        # Удалить item
        item = self.listWidget.takeItem(row)
        # Удалить widget
        self.listWidget.removeItemWidget(item)
        del item

    def doClearItem(self):
        # Clear all items
        for _ in range(self.listWidget.count()):
            item = self.listWidget.takeItem(0)
            self.listWidget.removeItemWidget(item)
            del item

    def testData(self):
        # Создать данные
        for i in range(10):
            item = QListWidgetItem(self.listWidget)
            item.setSizeHint(QSize(200, 60)) 
            
            widget = ItemWidget('item: {}'.format(i), item, self.listWidget)
            # Сигнал удаления привязки
            widget.itemDeleted.connect(self.doDeleteItem)
            self.listWidget.setItemWidget(item, widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]